# How to pass a string array like to stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using asp mvc c# and i want to know if it is possible to pass my string like array to IN operated in stored procedure. I have an example below:

C#

```
string temp="123,234,234";
```

SQL:

```
@temp varchar(50)
Select * from table where column in @temp
```

It returns

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '123,234,234' to data type int.
```

I wanted to pass is as stored procedure but got lost where to start now.

Things I've tried:

1. Try using Replace function but stil does not work.

Comment: As the error message says you would need to make your temp a integer instead of a varchar.

Comment: Please ensure that the tags you use relate to your specific question. `[vb.net]` and `[asp.net-mvc]` have no relevance here.

Comment: @earvin re the multi language tagging, it would be more acceptable if you'd said "I'll accept an answer in vb.net too because I know it" - generally if you've only used one language in the question you should only put that one tag

Comment: sorry i just used it again sorry for the wrong taggings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found, you can't do this, because a string containing numeric character sequences separated by commas is not the same as an SQL program that contains constant numbers separated by commas. For example, you wouldn't expect this c# to work either:

```
int[] a =  new [] { 1,2,3 }; //works
int[] b =  "new [] { 1,2,3 }"; //doesn't work
```

Nor would you expect this IN to work (which is really what you're doing:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE x IN('1,2,3')
```

If your column were a string, you wouldn't get an error but it wouldn't work like you expect either

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE x IN ('a','b'). --works
SELECT * FROM t WHERE x IN ('''a'',''b'''). --valid, but doesn't select x that are "a" or "b"
```

So, all in, IN is like a function that takes N arguments of various types. It doesn't look at a string you pass and see it has commas and split them

---

As such you either pass as many parameters as you have items:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE x IN (@p1, @p2, @p3)
```

Your sproc takes 3 parameters, you put one value per parameter, if you only seek two numbers you just repeat the last number because `IN(1,2,2)` is the same as `IN(1,2)`

---

Or you create a type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.IntList AS TABLE 
(
      X INT NOT NULL
)
```

You declare your sproc to take a variable of that type

```
@numList x
```

You declare a datatable in c# that represents that type

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("X", typeof(int));
```

You fill it with one int per row

You declare your param as Structured

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numList", dt).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

And you execute it. Remember that your @numList is a table like any other so you can't say `SELECT * FROM t WHERE x IN (@numlist)`, you either do `SELECT * FROM t JOIN @numList n ON t.x = n.x` or `SELECT * FROM t WHERE x IN (SELECT x FROM @numlist)` etc

Comment: Please note  "can we stop using AddWithValue" doesn't apply here